# Looking for a particular substring in SQL string

Tags: sql, substring, space, charindex

I'm trying to find some SQL code and having it doesn't seem to be returning my desired output.

Here is my create/insert statement

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    ([screenName] varchar(130), [realName] varchar(57))
;

INSERT INTO temp
    ([screenName], [realName])
VALUES
    ('WillyWonka', 'Will Stinson'),
    ('Barbara Smith', 'Barbara Smith'),
    ('JoanOfArc', 'JoanArcadia'),
    ('LisaD', 'Lisa Diddle')
;
```

What i'm looking for is the rows where the realName column has a space in it ... such as the first two and the fourth line ... and the realName the second word after the space Starts with the letter 'S' and is then followed by any character and then has the letter i, followed by any series of characters. This is where i'm stuck.

```
  SELECT LEFT(realName,CHARINDEX(' ',realName)-1)
  FROM
  temp
  Where LEFT(realName,CHARINDEX(' ',realName)-1) like 'S%'
```

although i'm pretty sure what i'm doing there is wrong but can't figure out how to make it correct.

apologies to the changes -- but how would i change the code if the name were to change and possibly have multiple space (`Jimmy Dean Stinson`) If I wanted to modify it to look from the right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM   temp
WHERE  realName LIKE '% S_i%'
```

Comment: But if I use like it will give me any combo's of S_i I only need it to be in the last/surname of the person. Like Skid Patington shouldn't be returned even though his first name is S_i. will this work on that too.

Comment: @Elizabeth Why `Skid Patington` should be rejected?

Comment: My apologies if i wasn't clear before - because we are looking for last names after the space it should read 'S_i%'

Comment: @Elizabeth - Updated check now

Comment: I changed the where to '% %S_i%'  us the wild card for one character and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to update that because  now i was asked for change to take into account if a name can have multiple spaces (many middle names).

Answer (score 0):

do you want

```
 SELECT LEFT(realName,CHARINDEX(' ',realName)-1)
  FROM
  temp
  Where realName like '% S_i%'
```

[wildcard single character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174424.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Second word of the name where it starts with `s` followed by another character followed by `i` followed by any number of characters:

```
 SELECT LEFT(realName,CHARINDEX(' ',realName)-1)
  FROM
  temp
  Where LEFT(realName,CHARINDEX(' ',realName)-1) like 'S_i%'
```

The underscore character `_` is a wild card for any single character.

You can find more wildcard characters for use with `LIKE` [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

You can do this to avoid the indexing error. That is happening on the values where there is no space. I added `%` to the like string which will ensure that the name has anything followed by a space, followed by your condition.

```
 SELECT LEFT(realName,CHARINDEX(' ',realName)-1)
  FROM
  temp
  Where realName like '% S_i%'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: That is happening on the values where there is no space. I made an edit to my answer to show another way to handle this that should not get that error.